# Mysql View in Laravel 5.2

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, sql-view

This might be simple for someone. But for me I am totally lost. Can anyone give me a heads up for using Mysql View in Laravel 5. I've been searching for relevant post for a while but not a clue except:

```
DB::statement("Create View")

DB::statement("Drop View")
```

But this doesn't ring a bell. Any help, any clue, any guide is appreciated. 
Thank in advance

**My Scenario**

> I have an **employee** table with other tables that holds various attributes of the employee separately such as `Appointment`, `posting`,`health`, `family` etc etc. Most of these tables has one property `Is_current` to represent the current record of the employee. So whenever I want to display employee profile with latest record or retrieve some latest record from some of these tables, I don't want to retrieve from each an every table one by one. I just want to compile the latest record in a `view` and retrieve from it whenever I want.

I hope you understand my requirements and sorry for my bad english

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve  ?

Comment: I'll update my question with that info then

Answer (score 3):

I use views all the time for reporting purposes as I can create a denormalized View and then use the power of Models with Scopes and mutators. I wrote an article on how I manage MySQL Views.

```
# Create a new migration
php artisan make:migration create_employees_record_view

# Update the migration
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateEmployeesRecordView extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        \DB::statement("
            CREATE VIEW employees_records 
            AS
            SELECT
                employees.emp_no,
                employees.first_name,
                employees.last_name,
                employees.gender,
                employees.hire_date,
                employees.birth_date,
                dept_emp.dept_no,
                departments.dept_name,
                mananger.emp_no AS manager_emp_no,
                mananger.first_name AS manager_first_name,
                mananger.last_name AS manager_last_name
            FROM
                employees
                LEFT JOIN dept_emp ON employees.emp_no = dept_emp.emp_no
                LEFT JOIN departments ON dept_emp.dept_no = departments.dept_no
                LEFT JOIN dept_manager ON departments.dept_no = dept_manager.dept_no
                LEFT JOIN employees mananger ON dept_manager.emp_no = mananger.emp_no;
        ");
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
    }
}

# Run the migration
php artisan migrate
```

Managing it via Console Command

```
php artisan make:command CreateOrReplaceEmployeeRecordsViewCommand

<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class CreateOrReplaceEmployeeRecordsViewCommand extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'view:CreateOrReplaceEmployeeRecordsView';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Create or Replace SQL View.';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        \DB::statement("
            CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW employees_records 
            AS
            SELECT
                employees.emp_no,
                employees.first_name,
                employees.last_name,
                employees.gender,
                employees.hire_date,
                employees.birth_date,
                dept_emp.dept_no,
                departments.dept_name,
                mananger.emp_no AS manager_emp_no,
                mananger.first_name AS manager_first_name,
                mananger.last_name AS manager_last_name
            FROM
                employees
                LEFT JOIN dept_emp ON employees.emp_no = dept_emp.emp_no
                LEFT JOIN departments ON dept_emp.dept_no = departments.dept_no
                LEFT JOIN dept_manager ON departments.dept_no = dept_manager.dept_no
                LEFT JOIN employees mananger ON dept_manager.emp_no = mananger.emp_no;
        ");
    }
}
```

Using Model To View
    # Create a new model
    php artisan make:model EmployeesRecord

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class EmployeesRecord extends Model
{
}
```

Test out the newly created Model

```
# For this we will be using tinker
php artisan tinker

>>> $e = \App\EmployeesRecord::first();
=> App\EmployeesRecord {#2885
     emp_no: 10001,
     first_name: "Georgi",
     last_name: "Facello",
     gender: "M",
     hire_date: "1986-06-26",
     birth_date: "1953-09-02",
     dept_no: "d005",
     dept_name: "Development",
     manager_emp_no: 110511,
     manager_first_name: "DeForest",
     manager_last_name: "Hagimont",
   }
>>> $e = \App\EmployeesRecord::where('emp_no', 10003)->first();
=> App\EmployeesRecord {#2896
     emp_no: 10003,
     first_name: "Parto",
     last_name: "Bamford",
     gender: "M",
     hire_date: "1986-08-28",
     birth_date: "1959-12-03",
     dept_no: "d004",
     dept_name: "Production",
     manager_emp_no: 110303,
     manager_first_name: "Krassimir",
     manager_last_name: "Wegerle",
   }
```

Ref - http://blog.tekz.io/laravel-eloquent-how-to-effectively-manage-sql-views/

Comment: this is great solution i implement it and it worked for me thanks. is there any new method to do it?

Comment: I am using console commands to manage the MySQL Views since it works flawlessly, I haven't had a chance to explore other options. Plus I like the fact it is much easier to update. If you don't use complex views I would say you can create simple scopes in any model and use ->join() methods.

Comment: Php artisan tinker is good and also migrate but refresh or reset dont remove views and when i use migrate error happened.

Comment: in your command you should use CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW rather than CREATE VIEW, then it will not give an error if view already exits, it will just update the definition.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this there is a good article [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20171027031909/http://programmingarehard.com/2013/11/10/eloquent_and_views.html)
I will show some code from the article .
Alter a base class like following:

```
public function save(array $options = [])
{
    $this->toWriteMode();

    try {
        $saved = parent::save($options);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->toReadMode();
        throw $e;
    }

    $this->toReadMode();

    return $saved;
}


protected $readOnly = [];

    protected $readOnlyCache = [];

    public function save(array $options = [])
    {
        $this->toWriteMode();
        $this->cacheReadOnly();

        try {
            $saved = parent::save($options);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->toReadMode();
            throw $e;
        }

        $this->toReadMode();
        $this->restoreReadOnly();

        return $saved;
    }

    protected function cacheReadOnly()
    {
        $this->readOnlyCache = [];

        foreach ($this->readOnly as $key) {
            $value = $this->getAttributeValue($key);
            $this->readOnlyCache[$key] = $value;
            $this->__unset($key);
        }
    }

    protected function restoreReadOnly()
    {
        foreach ($this->readOnlyCache as $key => $value) {
            $this->setAttribute($key, $value);
        }
    }
```

Create Employee model as follows:

```
class Employee extends BaseModel
{
    protected $table = 'employees';

    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function people()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Person');
    }
}
```

Create EagerEmployee class as follows:

```
class EagerEmployee extends Employee
{
    protected $readFrom = 'employeeView'; //Use your view name

    protected $readOnly = ['person_ids'];

    public function getPersonIdsAttribute($ids)
    {
        return $this->intArrayAttribute($ids);
    }
}
```

This class will read its data from the view and we can save and retrieve it as normal. It will fetch read only attributes and they will be handled appropriately when saving.

That new `intArrayAttribute()` method just converts the comma delimited id string returned from the view into an array of integers.

We can use the Employee internally but if we need those extra read only attributes, say in an api response, we can use the EagerEmployee class.

P.S. The above code is copied from the given article and changed according to your needs.

**Update:**
Since old link to article is broken I'm adding a link to cached page of the site.

[New Link to Article](http://web.archive.org/web/20171027031909/http://programmingarehard.com/2013/11/10/eloquent_and_views.html)

[Old Link to Article](http://programmingarehard.com/2013/11/10/eloquent_and_views.html/)

Comment: The link you provided is broken, please update the link or your answer.

Comment: Thanks @amey for pointing out. Since, I could not find any other reference for original article I have updated the link with cached copy of the article.

Answer (score -2):

```
'options'   => [
            \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true
]
```

[image]
Add Code to "config/database.php"
see picture below
[Show Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePwzo.png)